# How to abind plans of different dimensions?

Tags: r, addition, dimension

I have a matrix of dimensions `c(2,2,0)`. I would like to add a new row, but this new row is in fact a plan of dimensions `c(1,2,2)`.

I have already tried the `abind`function but it seems it does not work.

```
df = array(c(50,70,45,85), dim = c(2,2))
b = array(c(50,70,45,85), dim = c(1,2,2))

abind(df,b)
```

The expected result is expected to be an array in 3 dimensions, like b. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Yes indeed! I meant the new array has also a third dimension!

Comment: I totally understand you. The idea is to have dimensions = `c(3,2,2)`. Is it possible?